# Pandas: Expand column containing JSON encoded array of observations into rows

Tags: pandas

What is the idiomatic Pandas way to expand a column containing a JSON encoded array of observations into additional rows?

In the example below `Out[3]` is a `DataFrame` containing loan data. There is one row per loan. Columns `Loan ID`, `Start Date`, `End Date`, and `Amount` do not vary over the life of the loan. Zero or more date-stamped payments are encoded into the `Payments` column as a JSON (string) array.

[image: Jupyter screenshot]

The target output in `Out[5]` shows the goal. One or more rows per original row, with each payment from `Payments` resulting in the creation of a new row in the output.

I've done this two ways: with `iterrows`, which is sane-looking and easy to read, and with a convoluted, somewhat handwavy approach where I pull the fixed attributes into the index to preserve them, then `melt` and re-index.

There must be a better way! Please share the secrets of the pandas masters :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First remove `NaN`s in column `Payments` by [`dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dropna.html) and convert `json`s to `dict`s by [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
import ast

s = df['Payments'].dropna().apply(ast.literal_eval)
print (s)
0    [{'Payment Amount': 1000, 'Payment Date': '201...
Name: Payments, dtype: object
```

Then convert each value to `DataFrame` in `list comprehension` and [`concat`](http://pands.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) together - `keys` parameter is important for align to original rows:

```
df1 = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(x) for x in s], keys=s.index)
print (df1)
     Payment Amount Payment Date
0 0            1000   2018-03-11
  1            2000   2018-03-13
  2            3000   2018-03-15
```

Remove column and [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) to original `DataFrame`, last for unique index add [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
df = df.drop('Payments', 1).join(df1.reset_index(level=1, drop=True)).reset_index(drop=True)
df['Payment Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Payment Date'])
print (df)
   LoanId  Start Date    End Date  Amount  Payment Amount Payment Date
0     100  2018-01-01  2021-01-01   10000          1000.0   2018-03-11
1     100  2018-01-01  2021-01-01   10000          2000.0   2018-03-13
2     100  2018-01-01  2021-01-01   10000          3000.0   2018-03-15
3     101  2018-01-02  2021-01-02   20000             NaN          NaT
4     102  2018-01-03  2021-01-03   30000             NaN          NaT
```

Comment: Much appreciated. The `concat` step is the magic I was looking for, in particular the `keys=s.index` part.