# Pandas error reading csv with double quotes

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I've read all related topics - like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37074914/python-pandas-read-csv-quotechar-does-not-work#37076344), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32743479/pandas-read-csv-with-extra-commas-in-column) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26595819/double-quoted-elements-in-csv-cant-read-with-pandas) - but couldn't get a solution to work.

I have an input csv file like this:

```
ItemId,Content                                                      
i0000008,{"Title":"Edison Kinetoscopic Record of a Sneeze","Year":"1894","Rated":"N/A"}
i0000010,{"Title":"Employees, Leaving the Lumiére, Factory","Year":"1895","Rated":"N/A"}
```

I've tried several different approaches but couldn't get it to work. I want to read this csv file into a Dataframe like this:

```
ItemId    Content
--------  -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
i0000008  {"Title":"Edison Kinetoscopic Record of a Sneeze","Year":"1894","Rated":"N/A"}
i0000010  {"Title":"Employees, Leaving the Lumiére, Factory","Year":"1895","Rated":"N/A"}
```

With following code **(Python 3.9)**:

```
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', sep=',', skipinitialspace = True, quotechar = '"')
```

As far as I understand, commas inside dictionary column and commas inside quotation marks are being treated as regular separators, so it raises following error:

```
pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 4 fields in line 3, saw 6
```

Is it possible to produce desired result? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you'll be able to read it normally with pandas because it has the delimiter used multiple times for a single value; however, reading it with python and doing some processing, you should be able to convert it to pandas dataframe:

```py
def splitValues(x):
    index = x.find(',')
    return x[:index], x[index+1:].strip()

import pandas as pd
data = open('file.csv')
columns = next(data)
columns = columns.strip().split(',')
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns, data=(splitValues(row) for row in data))
```

**OUTPUT:**

```py
     ItemId                                                                          Content
0  i0000008   {"Title":"Edison Kinetoscopic Record of a Sneeze","Year":"1894","Rated":"N/A"}
1  i0000010  {"Title":"Employees, Leaving the Lumiére, Factory","Year":"1895","Rated":"N/A"}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the comma's in the `Content` column are interpreted as separators. You can solve this by using `pd.read_fwf` to manually set the number of characters on which to split:

```
df = pd.read_fwf('test.csv', colspecs=[(0, 8),(9,100)], header=0, names=['ItemId', 'Content'])
```

Result:

|  | ItemId | Content |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | i0000008 | {"Title":"Edison Kinetoscopic Record of a Sneeze","Year":"1894","Rated":"N/A"} |
| 1 | i0000010 | {"Title":"Employees, Leaving the Lumiére, Factory","Year":"1895","Rated":"N/A"} |

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem, and gives only the first key,value in the dictionary for each row

Comment: @ThePyGuy is correct. It didn't produce the desired results, only first key,value was read into Content column.

Comment: @thatOldITGuy You're right. I have updated the answer with a much simpler solution.

Comment: Good solution above.  After this the next step for the OP is to follow the [steps to expand the JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50054208/pandas-expand-column-containing-json-encoded-array-of-observations-into-rows) and the df is good.

Comment: @RJAdriaansen it is a good solution, but the real CSV has a much larger (and variable length) JSON column, so I guess the (9,100) column spec would have to be guessed, right?

Comment: @thatOldITGuy it will work fine as long as the number of characters in the first column is consistent, which seems to be the case. You can change 100 to a random number that is larger than the number of characters in the longest row